# Wiremock: How to define different responses based on percentage

Tags: wiremock

I want to use Wiremock to send 200 OK response to 99% of requests to one URL and 504 the other 1% of times. Is this possible?

Comment: If the solution proposed by agoff isn't something that works for you...I'd suggest [API Simulator](https://apisimulator.io) - out of the box it supports this and other uses of [Request Sampling](https://apisimulator.io/docs/1.6/standalone-api-simulator/response-configuration.html#request-sampling), no coding required. We see this employed in performance testing API clients to simulate error rates of real APIs. (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with API Simulator)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, but I would urge you to think about if this is really necessary. WireMock is meant to take out the guesswork associated with APIs, so that we know *for certain* that a particular response will be what we expect. I think a better use of WireMock would be writing responses for tests that intentionally return a 504 response.

But to answer your question as to how, this can be achieved using a [response transformer](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/). You'd simply have the transformer randomly generate a number. If that number is in your pass criteria, you'd just pass back the response as written. If that number is in your fail criteria, then you can pass back the custom 504 response. You can apply this transformer globally by *not* modifying the `applyGlobally` property.